# SQL table display error

Tags: sql

I am encountering a display issue with my SQL code and was hoping someone could help me figure out whats going on.  When I create my CUSTOMER table then INSERT a line of values it works successfully... however, when I type `select * from customer;` then it displays horrible output where none of the data is lined up in the columns properly.  Can you please take a look at my code and tell me what I can do to fix this.

I have multiple tables in this database and none of the other tables have this issue and display properly.  My window was configured using these two lines of code:

```
SET LINESIZE 132
SET PAGESIZE 50
```

My table creation code:

```
    CREATE TABLE  Customer
(
CustomerID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Customer_CustomerID PRIMARY KEY,
BillingID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
CustomerFName VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
CustomerLName VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
CustomerPhone VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
CustomerStreet VARCHAR2(30)NOT NULL,
CustomerCity VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
CustomerState CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
CustomerZip VARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL,
CustomerEmail VARCHAR2(75) NOT NULL,
SignUp_Date DATE DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL,
CustomerStatus CHAR(1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CC_Customer_CustomerStatus CHECK (CustomerStatus IN ('A', 'I')),
InactiveDate DATE,
InactiveReason VARCHAR2(200),
CustomerBillingCycle CHAR(1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CC_Customer_CustomerBC CHECK (CustomerBillingCycle IN ('A', 'B'))
);
```

My line of values being inserted into the table:

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (01234, 99012, 'Michael', 'Huffaker', '6235551414', '65 N 35th Ln', 'Glendale', 'AZ', '85308', 'm.huffaker@quickmail.com', '29-MAY-2010', 'A', NULL, NULL, 'A');
```

As I stated above, both of these work successfully and the problem appears when I display the data in the table.  Check out the screen shot link below to see the messed up output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMu4S.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not messed up at all; the output lines are just "wrapping" the output after 132 characters.  It's very normal. I don't use command line often for running selects, but try routing the output to a file.  Or perhaps try with a very large LINESIZE setting (like 1000 or so).  Your terminal windows may not support a line that wide.

Comment: Thank you very much!  My OCD wasn't letting the issue go... I like to make sure everything is 100% perfect.  Good to know I wasn't making a mistake somewhere.